# IBM Mainframe copy/paste

Tags: mainframe, zos

Disclaimer: I'm new to using Rumba to access IBM Mainframe.

I have currently set up a library for personal use and I have some code that I want to store in a member of this library, how can I copy/paste from a .txt file on my desktop into this program??? As of right now  I can successfully copy/paste one line at a time from documents outside of Rumba.

Comment: How big are these .txt files on average?

Comment: Be a little careful about "personal use". Bear in mind that if code is written on their system, an employer will likely consider it "theirs" unless you have have their permission.

Comment: files are about 300 lines long... not very large but need to be on 10-12 peoples systems...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various ways. The best one will depend upon the size of the file/amount of data to be transferred.

If it's only a few lines, block copy and paste should work, but you might have to play with Rumba's 'paste' edit settings such as how to handle new lines, etc.

Bigger files can be transferred with the TSO file transfer program ind£file (maybe ind$file on your system) which essentially copies a file to the screen and then Rumba 'scrapes' the screen for data to put into a file (this is for a mainframe-to-PC transfer; for going the other way the operation is reversed). This can be surprisingly quick.

Lastly there's FTP - either from the command line or via a program such as WinSCP.

## Edit:

Based on your comment that the files are about 300 lines long, I'd look into using Rumba's file-transfer option using the ind$file utility. Once you have the files on one system, speak to your mainframe tech support team about the best way to get them to the other systems.

If you need help uploading the files, then the tech support team should be your first point of call.

Answer (score 0):

What mainframe editor are you running?  TSO/ISPF? 
I copy and and paste from ".txt" files into ISPS all the time with no problem. 
Select the text you want to copy (in the ".txt" file)
Press CTRL-C
Open the mainframe file using ISPF Edit (option 2).
Enter line command "Inn" at the line where where you want the copy to start. 
(This inserts "nn" empty lines to receive the copied data.  Personally, I usually use "nn"=20) 
Position your cursor at the first character of the first empty line.
Press CTRL-V

Comment: Some 3270 emulators are actually able to paste more than one screen of text e.g, you 'copy' 200 lines  but can only 'paste' 20 following David's instructions about. - the emulator may then have a 'paste continue' option to paste lines 21-40 and then 41-60 etc etc. (Repeating the i20 in the ISPF editor as above).